# Which techniques to explore the stoichiometry of a thin film surface material?

Tags: x-ray-crystallography, technology

I wonder what other technological approaches are feasible to get the ratio of elemental distribution in the surface near layer of a coated (silicon) wafer. The layer thickness will be from several hundred nanometer to several micrometer.

Background: We want to measure the exact stoichiometry of a processed thin film on silica, materials involved include transition metals like Ti, V, Cr, Cu, Ag, Au and their respective oxides and nitrides. In the beginning of the Process the film will probably be amorphous, but we aim for crystal structure in the end.

Processes that we already consider to examine are X-Ray Diffraktion (XRD), Rutherford Backscattering Spectroscopy (RBS), Auger Electron Spectroscopy (AES) or X-ray photoelectron spectroscopy (XPS).

RBS and AES we consider to use to get a high element contrast and the ratio of found elements, XPS is, as far as I conclude not limited to surface electrons.
XRD will be applied when stoichiometry is found, to distinguish different crystallinities of the coating.

Are there any other techniques possible that are (mostly) destruction-free? Is it possible with any of these techniques (or other) to accomplish a depth resolved stoichiometry?

I know that this question might be close to start discussions, I don't want to discuss any analytical techniques, I'm searching for advantages and disadvantages of these (and possibly other) techniques for my special needs.
I'm also new to stackexchange, if I'm not in the right part of SE I'm sorry and would (re)move that question here.

Comment: You might consider adding ERD (Elastic Recoil Detection), a variant on RBS, to measure the oxygen/nitrogen/carbon content of the films. Under appropriate conditions (we were looking at tantalum oxides) you can pick the right beam and do both (silicon in that case backscatters off the tantalum, and forward scatters the oxygen). Also, x-ray fluorescence can help.

Comment: And I presume you are ruling out SIMS since it is destructive? Similar question on snapping the sample in half and using electron microprobe?

Comment: Another destructive technique is laser ablation mass spectrometry, to measure ratios of elements.  This can be depth-resolved.